# I want to get specific value's out of my JSON file with my Python script

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "WordsEntered": [
        {
            "Word": "test"
        },
        {
            "Word": "Test1"
        },
        {
            "Word": "Test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hi i want to get the data from this JSON file. I want to do this with a python script. I just want the python script to print the three words like: test, Test1, Test2. Can someone pls help me? Iam very new to python/json.

Comment: Not really because the script cant see whats inside WordsEntered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import json
# open file and read data
with open('your_json_data.json') as f:
    d = json.loads(f.read())# convert JSON text to python dictionary
    l = d['WordsEntered']
# print data
for d in l:
    print(d['Word'])
```

Comment: why not just `d = json.load(f)`? And using one-char names, especially like `l` is not good idea